# Retrieving data from the different file

Tags: angularjs

I've got a .json file with a bunch of objects in it. The question is basically how do I retrieve these and pass them to my .js file where retrieved objects will be outputted in the DOM one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply make an XHR like other request by just giving path to your json file. You can use angular's $http service to do that.

```
$http.get("yourFils.json").then(function(result){
console.log(result.data)
})
```

Comment: wat if its local issue

Comment: @Kirill You mean the file is on your disk on local machine?  That depends on what tool you are using for your app. If it's a simple app without any webpack so I'm afraid you have to use http for getting that file in js.

Comment: yeah, in the same folder with the script. when I use $http.get occurs an error. I dont how how this $http works though.

this kind ==>  ReferenceError: $http is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (angularScript.js:33)
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:41)
    at S.instance (angular.min.js:89)
    at p (angular.min.js:65)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)
    at angular.min.js:58
    at angular.min.js:21
    at m.$eval (angular.min.js:145)
    at m.$apply (angular.min.js:146)

Comment: You need to inject $http in controller or service where ever you are using it. controller('ctrl', function($http){$http.get("json file")})

Comment: oh, thank you, it works. And the last question, how to retrieve elements of an array from within this data. I thought the data will be the name of this object but after I changed it there was no changes actually.
Object {data: Array[1000], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: ""}

Comment: You are getting response as object because it's an json file. Simply do var data = result.data.